# Nothing displayed in Output window (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have been assigned to a project at work and I need to do some old-style debug because the Debug itself doesn't work with the libraries which are being used.

So, since it's a C++ with Qt application, I first tried with qDebug(). Then with cout, and finally with printf (which I hate in comparision to the former ones). NOTHING.

Nothing is written into the output window of Visual Studio 2008, and I'm quite sure it is executing these lines of code (I even tried to put a qDebug at the very beginning of the main.cpp). It is a GUI app by the way, and I've tried Debug output as well as Build output, but nothing is displayed.

I have looked for similar questions, but none of them provided a solution yet. Any help?

Comment: Try loading with [devenv /SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't use qDebug directly if it is not a console based application. Sounds weird to me, but sadly it is like that.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, your Visual Studio environment has been configured to redirect all output from the Output Window to the Immediate Window. I've been bitten by this a couple of times, as this is inexplicably a default setting for certain environment configurations.

To reset the setting, follow these steps:

1. From the "Tools" menu, select "Options".
2. Expand the "Debugging" item in the tree to the left, and select "General".
3. In the list to the right, scroll down to "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window", and ensure that it is *unchecked*.
4. Click OK to return sanity to the world.

[image]

Comment: It is unchecked. In fact, I did tried checking it, because I read about this somewhere. Checked or unchecked, nothing change.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was unchecked on mine so I checked it then unchecked it again and that seems to have resolved the issue for me.  Thanks for the tip.